# UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum with UIImageView in iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, swift2

I'm trying to develop a "Save image" feature in my App, where users can save the image from a TableView in their photo library. I have searched a lot through the community and I couldn't find anything related to my case, so I'm going to explain it:

As it says in the official guide, UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum has to receive a UIImage, so I'm trying to convert my UIImageView to a UIImage in order to achieve that, but when everything is fine without warnings or errors, the APP is displaying an error saying "Data unavailable".

**What I have to do to make it work? Am I sending the wrong data?**

```
<UIImage: 0x16db7780>, {400, 345}
```

**That's my code:**

```
func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo:UnsafePointer<Void>) {

    if error == nil
    {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Imagen guardada", message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


@IBAction func handleGesture(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.votarFrame?.hidden = true

    let guardarMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    var img:UIImage!

    img = self.productoImageView.image

    let saveImage = UIAlertAction(title: "Guardar imagen", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
    })

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)

    guardarMenu.addAction(saveImage)
    guardarMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.presentViewController(guardarMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take a snapshot of your `UIImageView` before calling `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`. Add following extension to `UIView` and call this function:

```
func takeSnapshot() -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.myImageView.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale);

    self.drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.myImageView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Abhinav, where I have to put that code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just removed this as extension to keep things simple for you. Put `takeSnapshot ` function in the same view controller you have all the above code and call it before calling `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum ` method. Ensure that your image view is saved in `self.myImageView `.